# Localization not working after changing to a new language

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm using localization to provide different languages for my app, so basically in my preference settings fragment, I have CheckBoxPreference for each language ( en - fr - es ), after clicking a certain checkbox, I save the language and language code in sharedpreference. The weird thing is that when I save the data, and return back to mainactivity, the localization is not working .

- This is how I'm saving language in SharedPreferences

```
  //Spanish Language 

 spanishCheckBox?.onPreferenceChangeListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
              val isChecked = newValue as Boolean
              val lang = "es"
              val langCode = "es-ES"
              if(isChecked){
                  englishCheckBox?.isChecked = false
                  frenchCheckBox?.isChecked = false
                  languageEditor.putString("lang",lang)
                  languageEditor.putString("langCode",langCode)
                  languageEditor.apply()
                  Intent(requireContext(),MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                      putExtra("language",languages[2])
                      putExtra("languageCode",languagesCodes[2])
                      startActivity(this)
                  }
              }
              isChecked
          }

 //French Language 
       frenchCheckBox?.onPreferenceChangeListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
              val isChecked = newValue as Boolean
              val lang = "fr"
              val langCode = "fr-FR"
              if(isChecked){
                  englishCheckBox?.isChecked = false
                  spanishCheckBox?.isChecked = false
                  languageEditor.putString("lang",lang)
                  languageEditor.putString("langCode",langCode)
                  languageEditor.apply()
                  Intent(requireContext(),MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                      putExtra("language",languages[1])
                      putExtra("languageCode",languagesCodes[1])
                      startActivity(this)
                  }
                  
              }
              isChecked
          }
```

- This is how i m retreiveing and setting locale configuration in my main activity

```
  private fun languagePreferences() {

      val languagePrefs = getSharedPreferences("langPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      val lang = languagePrefs.getString("lang", "en")
      val langCode = languagePrefs.getString("langCode", "en-US")

      val locale = Locale(lang!!, langCode!!)
      val configuration = Configuration()
      val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
      configuration.locale = locale
      resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics)

  }
```

PS : I'm executing the function before setContentView so before everything , basically the sharedpreferences is updated with new languge value but not changing the localization of the app , any help would be appreciated , thank you.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but check out this example: https://lokalise.com/blog/android-app-localization/ the differences are that they're setting the ``configuration`` and ``locale`` differently, because the approach you're using was deprecated in Android N. They're also using a ``ContextWrapper`` - basically using the normal Activity context, but overriding the resources without changing the original context. I don't know how much it matters, but it's worth a try. (I'm also assuming you're writing to the same ``SharedPreferences`` file you're loading in the activity!)

Comment: i actually figured out the issue , in my manifest file i added launchMode="singleInstance" for each activity thats supposed to be opened using intent , i removed that and everything is fine , thank you for your help